# Spring TemplateEngine and subdirectory

Tags: java, spring

I have issue with TemplateEngine.

I have mail template resolver which filld thymeleaf template based on name. It works well when I not specify subdirectory. Method looks like below:

```
private String getMailFromTemplate(MailMessage message) {
    Map<String, Object> objMap = new HashMap<>();
    objMap.putAll(message.getContext());

    Context context = new Context(message.getLocale(), objMap);
    return templateEngine.process(message.getTemplate().getName(), context);
}
```

And it is working correctly. But when i move templates to subdriectory called mail and change return line to

```
return templateEngine.process("mail/" + message.getTemplate().getName(), context);
```

Then it stopped working. Now I have exceptions:

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [start], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers (template: "mail/register" - line 1, col 6)
```

I tried also with "/mail/" but without success.

What is weird it works well in MVC controller, when for example I want to return page template which resides in subdirectory.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TemplateEngine is configured to use templates from a specific directory and when you try to process a template, it will expect its name to be passed as an argument and so 'mail/register' is a name.

you can configure templateEngine to read templates from your subdirectory like this:

```
@Bean
public ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/mail/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");

    return templateResolver;
}

@Bean
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
    templateEngine.setTemplateEngineMessageSource(messageSource());
    return templateEngine;
}
```